# Remove HTML field according to checkbox value

Tags: javascript, html, forms, checkbox

I want to remove HTML field according to Yes/No condition. Currently, all code that I am using I have submitted below to make understand better.

I want when I select Yes it will remove No Field/Input/Box & if I select No it will remove Yes Field/Input/Box.

```js
function AutoCheck() {
if (document.getElementById('yesCheck').checked) {
  document.getElementById('ifYes').style.visibility = 'visible';
} else {
  document.getElementById('ifYes').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}     

if (document.getElementById('noCheck').checked) {
  document.getElementById('ifNo').style.visibility = 'visible';
} else {
  document.getElementById('ifNo').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label class="radio">
  <label style="float: left; width: 90px;"><input name="auto" id="yesCheck" value="1" type="radio" onclick="javascript:AutoCheck();"> Auto</label>
  <label style="float: left; width: 90px;"><input name="auto" id="noCheck" value="0" type="radio" onclick="javascript:AutoCheck();"> Manual</label>
</div>
  
<div id="ifNo" style="visibility:hidden">
  <input id="mcstore_limit" name="mcstore_limit" placeholder="MAX Store Limit" type="number" min="1" step="1">
    
  <div id="ifYes" style="visibility:hidden">
    <input id="initial_limit" name="initial_limit" placeholder="MAX Store Limit" type="number" min="1" step="1">
    <input id="acstore_limit" name="acstore_limit" placeholder="Initial Store Limit" type="number" min="1" step="1">
    <input id="auto_limit" name="auto_limit" placeholder="Auto Increment Limit" type="number" min="1" step="1">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript isn't needed for hide/show if you are using radio buttons and/or checkboxes.  The following is required for a pure CSS solution:

#### HTML - Link Checkboxes/Radio Buttons and Labels

- Checkboxes and/or radio buttons with `#id`
- A label for each `chx` (a.k.a. checkbox(es)) and `rad` (a.k.a. radio button(s)) with `[for="`**#ID of chx or rad**`"]`

  - Each paired `chx/rad`|`label` combo are *linked* in a way that if the label gets clicked then its associated `chx/rad` is also clicked if both are in the same document.

    `<label` **for='ID'** `>REMOTE BUTTON</label>`

    `<input` **id='ID'** `type='checkbox'>`

---

#### CSS - :checked Pseudo-class and Adjacent Sibling Combinator

- Hide `chx/rad` and the elements you wish to `show/hide`.

  `input[type="radio"] {` **display:none** `}`
- For each `target` (a.k.a. `show/hide` element), place a `chx/rad` before it in HTML. This type of positioning is called *Adjacent Sibling*. In the perspective of the `chx/rad`, it must be the `chx\rad` first (like an older brother/sister) then `target` next (like a younger brother/sister).

  - A special CSS selector called the *Adjacent Sibling Combinator* can isolate a sibling pair (or pairs) using a "**+**" with or without the use of the usual `#id`, `.class`, or `[attribute]`:

    `input[type="radio"]` **+** `fieldset { display:none}`

    *Older Brother* **+** *Younger Brother* { *CSS style rules for Younger Brother*}

---

- Alternative positions can be used without the **ASComb** (a.k.a. *Adjacent Sibling Combinator*). Instead of `chx/rad` being the preceding sibling *older sister* to the `target`, it can be an ancestor. An ancestor is a parent element to the target, or simply put: the `target`'s parent, grandmother, great grandpa, etc.

  - Although it is a feasible selector, it is harder to isolate in complex and/or cluttered HTML layouts.

    `input[type="radio"]` `fieldset { display:none}`

    *Mother/Father*                 *Son/Daughter*

---

- `chx/rad` can invoke changes upon elements that are in certain positions in relation to the `chx/rad` when in and out of `checked` state. This `checked` state is more effective when `chx/rad` and `target` are isolated (using **ASComb**). The pseudo-class selector `:checked` acts like a switch if paired up as *Mom* and *Son* (ok) or *Big Sister* and *Little Brother* (best):

  - `:checked` applies to `chx/rad` state exclusively. The following example shows the final CSS rule with all the previously mentioned selector, and positioning.

    `input[type="radio"]`**:checked** **+** `fieldset {` **display:block** `}`

---

#### References

[**Exposing Form Fields Radio Button CSS**](https://css-tricks.com/exposing-form-fields-radio-button-css/)

[**The Checkbox Hack**](https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/)

[**Pure CSS Accessible Checkboxes and Radio Buttons**](https://medium.com/claritydesignsystem/pure-css-accessible-checkboxes-and-radios-buttons-54063e759bb3)

---

#### Demo

```css
.button {
  float: left;
  width: 90px;
  border: 3px ridge grey;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 19ch
}

[type='number'] {
  width: 8ch
}

#y,
#Y,
#N,
#n {
  display: none;
}

#N:checked+fieldset,
#Y:checked+fieldset {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Limits</legend>
  <label for='Y' class='button'>Auto</label>

  <label for='N' class='button'>Manual</label>
</fieldset>

<input id="N" name="auto" value="0" type="radio">

<fieldset id="n">
  <legend>Negative</legend>

  <label>MC MAX Store Limit:&nbsp;</label>
  <input id="mc" name="mc" type="number" min="1" step="1">

</fieldset>

<input id='Y' name="auto" value="1" type="radio" checked=true>

<fieldset id="y">
  <legend>Affirmative</legend>

  <label>Initial Store Limit:&nbsp;</label>
  <input id="init" name="init" type="number" min="1" step="1">
  <br>

  <label>AC MAX Store Limit:&nbsp;</label>
  <input id="ac" name="ac" type="number" min="1" step="1">
  <br>

  <label>Auto Increment Limit:&nbsp;</label>
  <input id="auto" name="auto" type="number" min="1" step="1">

</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your code, what's currently happening is that when the yesCheck is checked, everything is hidden.

By moving one of the extra  up to after the "mcstore_limit" input, it will then function correctly:

```
<div id="ifNo" style="visibility:hidden">
<input id="mcstore_limit" name="mcstore_limit" placeholder="MAX Store Limit" type="number" min="1" step="1">
</div>

<div id="ifYes" style="visibility:hidden">
<input id="initial_limit" name="initial_limit" placeholder="MAX Store Limit" type="number" min="1" step="1">
<input id="acstore_limit" name="acstore_limit" placeholder="Initial Store Limit" type="number" min="1" step="1">
<input id="auto_limit" name="auto_limit" placeholder="Auto Increment Limit" type="number" min="1" step="1">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay, I just checked your replay now, & I was done it earlier, & yes you are right by mistakenly I removed </div> thanks for your reply. Now I wat another info, when I select "Yes" its remove "No" but then if I select again "No" happen nothing I mean not restore the table until reload the page can I make different like if I Unchecked & checked again it will again restore the field...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, for a reply to all, I am using Jscripts to remove a field, because there is 2 field name same to input data into the database please look into the HTML code

```html
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12x; font-weight:bold" for="prefix">Select Storing Mode</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <label class="radio">
            <label style="float: left; width: 90px;">
                <input name="auto" id="yesCheck" value="1" type="radio" onclick="javascript:AutoCheck();"> Auto
            </label>
            <label style="float: left; width: 90px;">
                <input name="auto" id="noCheck" value="0" type="radio" onclick="javascript:AutoCheck();"> Manual
            </label>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
    
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12x; font-weight:bold" for="cstore_limit">Caller or Callee Store*</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <div id="ifNo" style="visibility:hidden">
            <input style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12x; font-weight:bold" id="cstore_limit" name="cstore_limit" placeholder="MAX Store Limit" type="number" min="1" step="1">
            <span class="footnote">Number Only, no space</span>
        </div>
        <div id="ifYes" style="visibility:hidden">
            <input style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12x; font-weight:bold" id="initial_limit" name="initial_limit" placeholder="MAX Store Limit" type="number" min="1" step="1">
            <span class="footnote">Number Only, no space</span><br>
    
            <input style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12x; font-weight:bold;margin-top: 5px;" id="cstore_limit" name="cstore_limit" placeholder="Initial Store Limit" type="number" min="1" step="1">
            <span class="footnote">Number Only, no space</span><br>
    
            <input style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;font-size:12x;font-weight:bold;margin-top: 5px;" id="auto_limit" name="auto_limit" placeholder="Auto Increment Limit" type="number" min="1" step="1">
            <span class="footnote">Number Only, no space</span><br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

see sir there is 2 field with the same name & id also cstore_limit to store in DB, but if I use CSS in DB storing value 0 because there is the same field trying to store. please let me know where I am wrong.